# Not able to pull up values from Firebase database on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON data structure in Firebase database:

```
familylist
 |- 0
    |--children
    |   |-- 0:"FGH"
    |   |-- 1:"HJU"
    |-- code: "2222"
    |-- family: "SWE"
    |-- fatherName: "ABC"
    |-- motherName: "XYZ"
 |- 1
    |--children
    |   |-- 0:"XXX"
    |   |-- 1:"YYY"
    |-- code: "3333"
    |-- family: "ABC"
    |-- fatherName: "ERT"
    |-- motherName: "XTS"
```

My code for retrieving `Children` data from firebase-database:

```
DatabaseReference childrenKeyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("familylist").child("children").child(key);
Log.d(TAG, "children: " + childrenKeyReference);
childrenKeyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String child = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Log.d(TAG, "Child : " + child);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

This are the details from LogCat. Null values are getting displayed. I'm not able to figure out what's wrong. Please do correct me.

```
05-22 21:25:29.771 24743-24743/D/tag: children: https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist/children/0
05-22 21:25:29.774 24743-24743/D/tag: children: https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist/children/1
05-22 21:25:29.780 24743-24743/D/tag: Child : null
05-22 21:25:29.805 24743-24743/D/tag: Child : null
```

**UPDATE**

New Result after setting the order properly. I'm getting this:

```
05-22 20:52:36.091 8572-8572/D/tag: children: https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist/0/children/0
05-22 20:52:36.097 8572-8572/D/tag: children: https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist/1/children/1
05-22 20:52:36.136 8572-8572/D/tag: Child : FGH
05-22 20:52:36.137 8572-8572/D/tag: Child : YYY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have switched the nodes *access order* by accident ;)

You are currently doing this:

```
...child("familylist").child("children").child(key);
```

but maybe you should be doing:

```
...child("familylist").child(key).child("children");
```

since, according to your datamodel, **familylist** clearly doesn't have a **children** child node.

Comment: As of now, I have 2 nodes `0` and `1`.  I'm able to only see the first value of `children` in `0` and last value of `children` in `1`
i.e., LOG CAT Details: 
`05-22 20:52:36.136 8572-8572/D/tag: Child : Pavan ( This is in 0 ) 
05-22 20:52:36.137 8572-8572/D/tag: Child : GGS ( This is in 1 )`

Comment: Sorry, but really not clear what you meant... maybe you should update your question (or ask a new question if this is another issue you are having).